# Liquid replace only for <p> contained in <blockquote>

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to update the class of `<p>` contained in `<blockquote>` but I can't reach it using the liquid "replace" command

I can't seem to find a proper solution

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="container is-fluid ">
            <div class="columns is-medium content is-multiline is-centered">
                <div class="column is-10 ">
                    {{ content | markdownify | smartify 
                        | replace: '<table', '<table class="table is-narrow is-bordered is-hoverable is-striped is-size-6 column is-8 is-offset-2"'
                        | replace: '<blockquote', '<blockquote class="column is-8 is-offset-2"'
                        | replace: '<p', '<p class="column is-8 is-offset-2"'
                        | replace: '<h1', '<h1 class="column is-8 is-offset-2"'
                        | replace: '<h2', '<h2 class="column is-8 is-offset-2"'
                        | replace: '<h3', '<h3 class="column is-8 is-offset-2"'
                        | replace: '<h4', '<h4 class="column is-8 is-offset-2"'
                        | replace: '<h5', '<h5 class="column is-8 is-offset-2"'
                        | replace: '<h6', '<h6 class="column is-8 is-offset-2"'
                        | replace: '<ul', '<ul class="column is-8 is-offset-2" style=" padding-left: 3em;"' 
                        | replace: '<bloquote p', '<blockquote p class=""' 


                }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
<section class="section is-normal has-background-light">
    {% include post-nav-buttons.html %}
</section>
```

The problem now is with this solution

```
<p class="column is-8 is-offset-2"'> Some text </p>

<blockquote class="column is-8 is-offset-2"'>
     <p class="column is-8 is-offset-2"'>
            My quote text
     </p>
</blockquote>
```

I don't want to have `class="column is-8 is-offset-2"'` applied to `<p>` in `<blockquote>`

If someone knows how I can target those specific p using this liquid filter ?

Comment: Are you able to add a custom filter? If you can enable regular expressions in your replace filter (e.g., `regex_replace`), then you could use regex to handle that complicated nesting scenario. Otherwise, can this be handled on the front end with JavaScript? From what I can see, this is a job for jQuery or a any script that can rewrite elements at the DOM level.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work if indentation is exactly the same:

```
  {%- capture editable_part -%}
  <blockquote class="column is-8 is-offset-2">
       <p class="column is-8 is-offset-2">
  {%- endcapture -%}
  {%- capture new_part -%}
  <blockquote class="column is-8 is-offset-2">
    <p>
  {%- endcapture -%}          
  {% if content contains '<blockquote class="column is-8 is-offset-2">' %}
  {{ content | replace: editable_part,new_part }}
  {% else %}
  {{ content }}
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I 100% got it working, by removing all of the JS and doing everything in Liquid. Using the following.

```html
<span class="answerspan{{ faq.faq_link_pid }}">
  {%- capture editable_part -%}
   <a href="{{ faq.hyper_link }}" target="_blank">{{ faq.link_description }}</a>
  {%- endcapture -%}
  {% if faq.answer contains 'aaaa ' %}
  {{ faq.answer | replace: 'aaaa ', editable_part }}
  {% else %}
  {{ faq.answer }}
  {% endif %}
</span>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).